# Simplify Google Map JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am using the Google Maps API code to initialize 3 google maps on one page.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adamjesmith/e53yjye8/

The below code works fine but I was wondering if there is anyway I can simplify the JavaScript so I am not doing the same thing 3 times? Possibly using a for loop to through the number of maps?

```
function initialize() {
///// Stamford Bridge /////
var optionsSB = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: {lat:  51.481663, lng: -0.19095649999997022},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false
}
mapSB = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("stamford-bridge"), optionsSB);
var markerSB = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat:  51.481663, lng: -0.19095649999997022},
    map: mapSB,
    icon: '/images/map-pin.png'
});
var infowindowSB = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content:"<h3>Stamford Bridge</h3>"
});
infowindowSB.open(mapSB, markerSB);

///// O2 /////
var optionsO2 = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: {lat:  51.5030431, lng: 0.00423769999997603},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false
}
mapO2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("o2"), optionsO2);
var markerO2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat:  51.5030431, lng: 0.00423769999997603},
    map: mapO2,
    icon: '/images/map-pin.png'
});
var infowindowBow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content:"<h3>O2</h3>"
});
infowindowBow.open(mapO2, markerO2);

///// London Zoo /////
var optionsZoo = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: {lat:  51.5352875, lng: -0.15343029999996816},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false
}
mapZoo = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("zoo"), optionsZoo);
var markerZoo = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat:  51.5352875, lng: -0.15343029999996816},
    map: mapZoo,
    icon: '/images/map-pin.png'
});
var infowindowZoo = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content:"<h3>London Zoo</h3>"
});
infowindowZoo.open(mapZoo, markerZoo);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your map-marker-infowindow creation in a factory-like function:

```
function createMapWithStuff(options) {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(options.id), options);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: options.center,
        map: map,
        icon: '/images/map-pin.png'
   });
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
           content:"<h3>"+options.content+"</h3>"
   });
   infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }

  function initialize() {
    ///// Stamford Bridge /////
    var theoptions=[ {
        zoom: 15,
        center: {lat:  51.481663, lng: -0.19095649999997022},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel: false,
        content:'Stamford Bridge',
        id:'stamford-bridge'
    },{
        zoom: 15,
        center: {lat:  51.5030431, lng: 0.00423769999997603},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel: false,
                content:'O2',
        id:'o2'
    },{
        zoom: 15,
        center: {lat:  51.5352875, lng: -0.15343029999996816},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel: false,
        content:'London Zoo',
        id:'zoo'
    }];

    theoptions.forEach(function(optionObject) {
        createMapWithStuff(optionObject);       
    });

  }
```

[<kbd>See the fiddle</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/8jx87xae/)